# Draw an HTML element on a Photoshop layer

Tags: javascript, draw, layer, photoshop-script

I need to display a simple html element on a layer on Photoshop using extendscript (JavaScript).

Does someone have any idea how to do this please ?

Here is the html element :

```
<div class="number">1</div>

.number {
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5; 
}
```

Comment: Do you just want to create an image with those parameters?

Comment: I would like to display this element on a layer for a given position. I must not interact with it, it's just for display :) I'd rather not have to save an image locally first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find how to draw an html element, but drawed a rectangle on a layer, created a text layer, then merge the both layers together :)